# How do I determine whether a UIImage is empty?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

How do I check to see if a `UIImage` is empty?

```
class UserData {
    ...
    var photo: UIImage = UIImage()
}
```

My `ViewController` code looks like:

```
var userData = UserData()
    ...

func preparePhoto(){
        if (self.userData.photo == nil) {
            ...
        }else{
            ...
        }
    }
```

`self.userData.photo == nil` won't work in Swift.

Xcode says: `UIImage is not convertible to MirrorDisposition`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`self.userData.photo` will *never* be nil, so the question is pointless.

The reason is that you have declared `photo` as a UIImage. That is not the same as a `UIImage?` - an Optional wrapping a UIImage. Only an Optional can be nil in Swift. But, as I just said, `photo` is *not* an Optional. Therefore there is nothing to check. That is why Swift stops you when you try to perform such a check.

So, what to do? I have two possible suggestions:

- My actual recommendation for solving this is that you *do* type `photo` as a `UIImage?` and set it initially to nil (actually, it is implicitly nil from the start). Now you can check for nil to see whether an actual image has been assigned to it.

  But keep in mind that you then will have to remember to unwrap `photo` when you want to use it for anything! (You could instead type `photo` as an implicitly unwrapped optional, `UIImage!`, to avoid that constant unwrapping, but I am not as keen on that idea.)
- An alternative possibility would be to examine the *size* of the image. If it is zero size, it is probably an empty image in the original sense of your question!

Comment: Of cause thats make sene. I just made the photo property and Optonal, and now it is working...

Comment: @MortenGustafsson If the matter is settled, please either give your own answer and accept it or accept mine, to mark the question as answered for future readers. Thanks.